# Bourne Shell - Read and print tab from file

Tags: shell, tabs, echo, sh

I am trying, so far unsuccessfully to read and print a tab character from a file in a Bourne shell script.

For example, here is my file, in.txt (stackoverflow won't let me write a tab, so replace [tabcharacter] with a tab):

```
[tabcharacter]Hello World!
```

My script as as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line
do
echo -e "${line}" >> out.txt
/bin/echo -e "${line}" >> out.txt
done < "./in.txt"
```

The out.txt I get is:

```
-e hello!
hello!
```

Whereas I would expect from one of these the output to be the same as in.txt.

I think it's a problem with the way I use the read command. But I'm not sure how I can get it to read tabs.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
export IFS=
while read line
do
echo -e "$line" >> out.txt
/bin/echo -e "$line" >> out.txt
 done < "./in.txt"
```

I seted the IFS variable to a empty string, now its working, please test it!

Comment: Try now! i made a little modification

Comment: If this works, please mark the question as right, so others users will be able to search!